# Select By Attribute in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

We can select features and display their attributes in OpenLayers. But I', curious can we add a tool similar to arcgis "Select by Attribute" in OpenLayers interface.

Answer (score 2):

See the getFeaturesByAttribute function applicable to Vector layers: http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getFeaturesByAttribute